# D3 updating data but not axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating an interactive bar chart in D3. When a button is pressed the data changes.

Here's simplified code for the bar chart:

```
<svg class="cex"></svg>
<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 35},
    width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height =  300- margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("left");

  var cex = d3.select(".cex")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("/input.csv", function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.City; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.EatIn; })]);

  cex.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(60)")
      .style("text-anchor", "start");;

  cex.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  var bar=cex.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.City); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.EatIn); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.EatIn); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

});
function type(d) {
  d.EatIn = +d.EatIn;
  return d;
}
```

When a button is selected the following update code runs:

```
function EatOutData() {
        d3.csv("/input.csv", function(error, data) {
          x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.City; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.EatOut; })]);
        var sel = cex.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data);
        sel.exit().remove();
        sel.enter().append("rect")
          sel.attr("class", "bar")
          sel.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.City); })
          sel.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.EatOut); })
          sel.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.EatOut); })
          sel.attr("width", x.rangeBand());

             sel.selectAll("g.y.axis")
              .call(yAxis);

            sel.selectAll("g.x.axis")
              .call(xAxis);
  function type(d) {
  d.EatOut = +d.EatOut;
  return d;
}
  }
    )};
```

The update changes the Y variable. So the height of the bar changes but the axis doesn't change and the scale of the two variables are quite different.

There have been a couple other SO posts on this but none seemed to fix it for me. I'm not sure why the y.domain in the update doesn't adjust them. Would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: what is in input.csv? post your sample data

Comment: Will need to see your csv file and format of the data to verify if d3.max is indeed changing when the data is updating.  Mind posting that? Meanwhile you can also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017214/d3-js-max-and-min-value-from-json-data-which-has-array-of-values) post to see if it fits your bill in calculation

Comment: You can find the data here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katerabinowitz/CEX-Cities/master/MSA-CEX-prop.csv - notice difference in scales b/w EatIn and Alcohol. I do not think this is a max issue bc if I build both graphs independently the scales are appropriate for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the axis (or the text) and draw it again just like you are removing the bars and plotting them again to update data on the axis. Check the [working plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/n8BGd0JAlI4JylKUwhsQ?p=preview).

```
function EatOutData() {

    d3.csv("input2.csv", function(error, data) {

      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.City; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.EatOut; })]);


    var sel = cex.selectAll("rect")
         .data(data);
    sel.exit().remove();
    d3.select(".x.axis").remove();

    sel.enter().append("rect")
      sel.attr("class", "bar")
      sel.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.City); })
      sel.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.EatOut); })
      sel.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.EatOut); })


      sel.attr("width", x.rangeBand());

    cex.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(60)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");;


         sel.selectAll("g.y.axis")
          .call(yAxis);

        sel.selectAll("g.x.axis")
          .call(xAxis);
function type(d) {
d.EatOut = +d.EatOut;
return d;
}
}
)};
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking to update the Y but took your code and flipped it to Y.